# Sum particular cells only if matched a particular string from a dropbox

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query, gs-vlookup

I have this Project Costing spreadsheet, where I track all my project profit, expense etc.
The number of items in every project is always different. Then I have a few states of the projects such as: in progress, invoiced, paid, closed etc.

[image]

What I need is to get a sum of all my sales, cost and profit ONLY of the projects that are Closed. You can see in the top line of each project I have a data validation cell where I select the state of the project. Once it's closed I need to add its sales, cost and profit into the top cells (orange, blue & green).

I can't for the life of me, figure out how to do that. Tried sumif plus queries no luck. Any ideas?

Here is a sample of the spreadsheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18Y-2jeKue9aH4gGdKHZjECygo47JFOp2W11C2sy7fJk/edit?usp=sharing

EDIT:
I found a workaround. by repeating the status of the project in the cell next to Total: cell. and then just simply using `=SUM(QUERY($B$26:$M$46,"select M WHERE B = 'Closed'"))`. But I am sure there are more elegant and robust ways of solving my problem.
Cause sometimes I have cases when only 50% of the whole sale price was paid(upfront payments), so I'd like to reflect that as well.

Comment: sheet is private

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are not happy with your workaround you can do:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(QUERY({VLOOKUP(ROW(A12:A), IF(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(K12:K, 
 "Undefined|Quote|Accepted|In-progress|Cancelled|On-hold|Not Paid|Paid 50%|Closed"))<>"", 
 {ROW(A12:A), K12:K}), 2, 1), C12:C, M12:N}, 
 "select Col3 where lower(Col1) = 'closed' and lower(Col2) = 'total:'", 0)))
```

and for Profit:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(QUERY({VLOOKUP(ROW(A12:A), IF(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(K12:K, 
 "Undefined|Quote|Accepted|In-progress|Cancelled|On-hold|Not Paid|Paid 50%|Closed"))<>"", 
 {ROW(A12:A), K12:K}), 2, 1), C12:C, M12:N}, 
 "select Col4 where lower(Col1) = 'closed' and lower(Col2) = 'total:'", 0)))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: wow, this is some formula. Could you elaborate a little bit about what is going on there? thank you

Comment: sure, this formula creates a virtual column of statuses for each row until it finds another one and it repeats it down for each row etc. then query just filter out necessary rows from the rest and a SUM is performed

Comment: in regards to 50%... so you want to sum all closed statuses and all 50% statuses?

Comment: No, some times the status is Paid 50%, so I have to reflect that in the overall sum.

Comment: in other words. Status "Paid" sums up the whole sale, cost and profit. If the status is "Paid 50%". Then only 50% of the whole sale, profit and cost sum should be summed up.

Comment: ah I see what you did. I'm still trying to figure out the formula. It looks quote advanced for me. But I believe you answered my question anyway

Comment: Could you explain why do you need to query through C12:C?

Comment: sure, its for "Total:" because only that row is important

Comment: ah yeah.. see it now. thanks! It's just my actual sheet is quite huge and when Im going through the formula I can't see the bottom of my project table. cudnt figure out what would you search in this column.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199194/discussion-between-alex-reds-and-player0).

Comment: are you here? I need to expand your formula. Still, don't understand how it works

Comment: I need to aggregate the totals by clients. But I see your formula depends on Total: which is in the same column as clients name. Is it possible to do? Not sure if i want to create a new question